# java extends abstract class

Tags: java, классы

Как создать абстрактный класс с полем которое должно быть обязательно нициализировано?

Answer (score 3):

Близко к тому решение...можно объявить конструктор у абстрактного класса и после унаследования обязательно нужно будет вызвать его...собственно там и проинициализируете поле.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    protected String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(String type) {
        super(type);
    }

}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog("Aaa");
        System.out.println(animal.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Конструктор абстрактного класса принято объявлять `protected` и во вторых это не спасет, если будет вызван дефолтный конструктор (который всегда есть)

Comment: На счет protected согласен(но это не так важно к заданию), а на счет дефолтных конструкторов не согласен...если есть уже один конструктор, то дефолтного нет...в том коде, который я предоставил, если в конструкторе Dog попытаться вызвать super(), то будет ошибка компиляции. Если не сложно покажите пожалуйста вариант в моем примере, где можно обойти инициализацию с дефолтным конструктором.

Comment: Да, вы правы, дефолтный конструктор появляется если не задано ни одного конструктора, а если он объявлен - то его не будет. Я ошибся.

Answer (score 1):

Обязать инициализировать поля не выйдет, но подобное можно сделать через абстрактные геттер-функции, например:

```
abstract class AbstractFooBar {
    public abstract String getValue();
}

class MyFoo extends AbstractFooBar {
    private static final String VALUE = "Foo";

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return VALUE;
    }
}

class MyBar extends AbstractFooBar {
    private static final String VALUE = "Bar";

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return VALUE;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyFoo foo = new MyFoo();
        System.out.println(foo.getValue());    // Foo

        MyBar bar = new MyBar();
        System.out.println(bar.getValue());    // Bar

        AbstractFooBar fooBar = new MyBar();
        System.out.println(fooBar.getValue()); // Bar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто:

```
public abstract class Abstract {

    protected String initMe = getInitMe();

    protected abstract String getInitMe();
}
```

Неабстрактные наследники этого класса будут обязаны реализовать `getInitMe()` и тем самым инициализировать поле `initMe`.